# Realm, complex linked query

Tags: android, realm, realm-java

in the official docs, https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#link-queries - there's an example how to select owners of "Brown Fluffy" dogs.

My questions is, how do I select only those *not having* Brown Fluffy (and, obviously, those having no dogs at all)

I do not see how can one achieve this result by, say, using `.not().beginGroup().equalTo(...).equalTo(...).endGroup()` (that someone with previous SQL experience would try)

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
.not().equalTo(...).findAll().where().not().equalTo(...).findAll();
```

?

Chaining link queries is a bit tricky, but if I understand correctly, that is what you should try.

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce, I need to check it. I really feel that something like "Realm queries for those thinking in tables/SQL" is something needed. Do I understand it right that `.equalTo()` for a linked entity is more or less close to `HAVING` or `EXISTS` clause in SQL? ;)

Comment: EqualTo is more like `==`

Comment: Yes sure, for the object's own fields, but behaves a bit different when filtering on linked objects, right?

Comment: Ah yeah, in that case it's kinda like `if there is at least one linked object that ___ then`